# Appending jquery to website by chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I made some chrome extension, it works but I want to use jquery because it is easier.

My extension javascript file contains:

```
$('body').append('<script src="/someFreeHost/jquery.js"></script><script src="/someFreeHost/file.js"></script>');
```

And when I try to use jquery code inside file.js, I get error like jquery wasn't inserted. But when I use regular js code everything works.

json file contains:

```
"content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["jquery.js","main.js"]
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest content script tries loading a local jquery.js first, then main.js. If you're not providing a local copy of jquery.js, then calling $('body') will pop an error

You can either append script tags using vanilla JS, or you can provide a local copy of jquery.js with your extensions

Edited from original because I thought dynamically appending script tags wouldn't cause them to load